# Eclipse PhoneGap load old www files

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I have updated my files for the project. When I load the index.html inside eclipse it seems good.
But once I run it on the phone, (using Genymotion) it seems to load an old version of the index.html..

I have tried delete the app from the phone and installed it again, not work. 
Also tried refresh / restart eclipse without success.

Anyone knows the problem?

Comment: Are you editing from `{project_name}/www` or `{project_name}/platforms/android/www`?

Comment: I'm editing in the `{project_name}/www`.. This is wrong? :)

Comment: Sorry, follow up question: how are you building to the device? if you are deploying with eclipse, you should be working in the `platform` folder. If you are using the cordova CLI to deploy, you should be working in the main `www`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Genymotion but it seems to me that the www files are not being updated under the platform specific folder. In your case your-project/platforms/android/assets/www.

Maybe try to run emulate or run your app from the command line.

cordova run android or
cordova emulate android

hope it helps.

PS: Have you also tried using Netbeans for debugging and testing phonegap/cordova apps. It has out-of-the-box support and works quite nice and quick. Simply imp[ort your project "New Project" > HTML5 > HTML5 application with existing sources > click next >  then select your www folder udner "Site root" and your done.

Comment: Oh, you are so right. Am I supposed to make the changes to the www folder in assets? Not in the other one?

Comment: as cordova is meant to be multiplatform, you're supposed to make changes in the root www folder, but then you need to run `cordova prepare android` to update the platforms/android folder. Or if you only care about one platform and don't want to use the CLI, you can care about only the platforms/android folder but in this case you must no more use the CLI or you may loose all your changes. In that case you'd have to use plugman to manage plugins instead of the CLI.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to run `cordova prepare android` .. :)